# Play for Scala: Catch HTTP JSON request error

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In the code below, I receive an http `request` in json format and convert it to an object of class MyRequest. This works fine if all the fields are present in the json request, however crashes with `JsResultException` if one or more fields are missing. What is the best way to catch the error?

```
  request => val json = request.body
  val req = json.as[MyRequest]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I prefer construction with match. Maybe you will like it too

```
def doSomethingWithJsonRequest = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[FooRequest] match {
      case s: JsSuccess[FooRequest] =>
        Ok(processFoo(s.get))
      case e: JsError =>
        BadRequest(handleError(e))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `as[T]` use `validate[T]` which gives you a `JsResult[T]`. It's explained in the Play documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Using-validation).

From there, you can `fold` it and elegantly handle the problem. Typically I like to send a summary of the problem back to the caller **as JSON**, which is a lot nicer than the "500 - Internal Server Error" **HTML page** that you get when using `as[T]`. At the very least, by returning a `4xx` code instead of a `500`, it puts the blame back on the *caller* - it was them who sent us invalid JSON after all!

Example:

```
/** 
 * You can use this method as the error 
 *  handler wherever you fold on a validate[T]  
 */
def handleBadJson(problems:Seq[(JsPath, Seq[ValidationError])]):Future[Result] = {
  val jsProblems = problems.map { case(path, errs) =>
    val jsErrs = errs.map(err => JsString(err.message))
    path.toString -> JsArray(jsErrs)
  }

  Future.successful(BadRequest(JsObject(jsProblems)))
}

def doSomethingWithJsonRequest = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[Foo].fold(handleBadJson, goodFoo => {
    ...
  })
}
```